# Compile Error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

Recently updating my project from Symfony 2.6 to Symfony 3.4. I received the following error while running my app:

> (1/1) FatalErrorException
> Compile Error: Declaration of
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder::set($id,
> $service) must be compatible with
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface::set($id, >$service, $scope = self::SCOPE_CONTAINER)
>
> in ContainerBuilder.php line 51

Please help me resolve the problem?

Comment: Do you have followed symfony doc about [upgrading major version](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/upgrade_major.html) ?

Comment: Yes, I have followed the documentation thoroughly and made updated according to that @Pouette

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace and can you check which version of Symfony you have installed right now? Both [ContainerBuilder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php#L525) and [ContainerInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerInterface.php#L38) have a matching signature in the 3.4-branch of Symfony. So maybe this is caused by an older version?

Comment: [From](https://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerInterface.html) "Note: The $scope parameter is deprecated since version 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0." You have a mixture of old code and new code.  Upgrading that far is quite a leap.  I would suggest making a new 3.4 project, adding your additional third party bundles, and then use the generated composer.json file.

Comment: Hi @Cerad I have been using in that way, but still facing a lot of issue i that

Comment: Issues related to SCOPE_CONTAINER or something else?  In any event, you really should move from 2.6 to 2.8 and then fix all the depreciation messages.  Then jump to 3.4.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm facing the same issue. I have updated from 2.7 to 2.8 and then from 2.8 to 3.4